# Mysql. JOIN to small table blocks using indexes on the main one

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

MySQL version 5.7.17

When I use JOIN for small tables, MySQL don't allow me to use index on the main table.

Compare:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `ko_base_client_orders`.*
FROM `ko_base_client_orders`
  LEFT JOIN `ko_base_new_perspe` AS `ko_of`
     ON (`ko_of`.`id` = `ko_base_client_orders`.`office`)
ORDER BY `order_time` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                                                           |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ko_base_client_orders | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 60737 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ko_of                 | NULL       | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |     2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

and the same query with index hint:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `ko_base_client_orders`.*
FROM `ko_base_client_orders`
  LEFT JOIN `ko_base_new_perspe` AS `ko_of`
         FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (`PRIMARY`)
         ON (`ko_of`.`id` = `ko_base_client_orders`.`office`)
ORDER BY `order_time` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                             | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ko_base_client_orders | NULL       | index  | NULL          | order_time | 6       | NULL                            |   10 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ko_of                 | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | e3.ko_base_client_orders.office |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

In second case MySQL uses key for order_time, but in first example it ignores index and scans the entire table.

I can not predict which table would be small, and which would not (it differs from project to project), so I don't want to use index hints all the time. Is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  Also, how big is each table?  Is there some reason for using `LEFT`?  Which table is `order_time` in?  (Please qualify all columns when joining.)

Comment: It's similarly strange that the wrong solution (index hint) fixes the real problem (not using the order_time index), which should be the obvious strategy.  `rows` showing `2` on the `PRIMARY` join in the first plan is also strange.  This smells like an optimizer bug but definitely need the create table statements.  Does anything change if you run `ANALYZE TABLE` against the two tables?